# Scroll to div smoothy after page load and not directly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a php page and I am trying to scroll user to section automatically after entire page is loaded. Right now it takes directly to that section on page load, I want entire page to be loaded and then scroll the page to that div. What I am doing is.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function gotoit()
{
window.location="#gohere";
}
//-->
</script>

<body onload="gotoit()">
some code here
<a name="gohere"><div class="I want to scroll to this div"></a>
```

Please help me what should I do to scroll smoothly to that section automatically after page load.

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(window).load(function() {
        var theHash = "#go-here";
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop:$(theHash).offset().top}, 800);
      });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Lots of content here...</p>
    <p>More content...</p>
    <p>etc...</p>
    <p id="go-here">Scroll down to here automagically</p>
    <p>Some more content</p>
</body>
</html>
```

$(window).load() ensures the page starts to scroll after all your other assets have loaded (images, for example).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jQuery function I use to achieve this:

```
function scrollToStart(){
$("#scrollToStart").click(function (){
       $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $("#startHere").offset().top
     }, 2000);

});
};
```

Comment: That code should be in header? and how should I load the body? just <body> will work?